# Bootstrap Fileinput js Issue in Filepreremove function

Tags: jquery, angular

When we click on delete button it's works first time, second time it's(event.target.files) become null for newly uploaded images.
please below code written in angular 2

```
    $("#input-fcount-1").fileinput({
        uploadUrl: "/file-upload-batch/2",
        maxFileCount: 4,
        validateInitialCount: true,
        overwriteInitial: false,
        initialPreview: [
            "<img class='kv-preview-data file-preview-image' src='https://placeimg.com/800/460/nature'>",
            "<img class='kv-preview-data file-preview-image' src='https://placeimg.com/800/460/nature'>",
            "<img class='kv-preview-data file-preview-image' src='https://placeimg.com/800/460/nature'>"
        ]
 })
        .on('filepreremove', function(event, id, index) {
                        var deletedFileName = event.target.files[index].name;
        });
```

Please any suggestion or i am missing something to the code.

Comment: code is not angular2 but you can use `filebeforedelete` event

Comment: yes, this one is JQuery Code which we have integrated into the Angular 2 application,  we had use this one too., but problem is  " event.target.files " becomes null when we click on another newly uploaded images